# I'm not sure if my game is working yet

Tags: c#, winforms, tracelistener

My friend and I have been working on a game and we have a trace listener set up, here's some of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GuiGame {

/// <summary>
/// A type of Trace Listener that sends its output to a ListBox.
/// </summary>
public class ListBoxTraceListener : TraceListener {

    private ListBox listBox;  // A reference to the listbox that we're writing to.

    private string stringToAddToListBox = "";

    private const char NEW_LINE = '\n';

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameterless constructor.
    /// Do not want the generic default constructor to be used
    /// as there is no way to set the ListBoxTraceListener's data.
    /// This replaces the compiler's generic default constructor.
    /// Pre:  none
    /// Post: ALWAYS throws an ArgumentException.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>NOT TO BE USED!</remarks>
    public ListBoxTraceListener() {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameterless constructor invalid.");
    } // end ListBoxTraceListener constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor with initialising parameters.
    /// Pre:  the existence of a ListBox on a GUI form.
    /// Post: initialised object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listBox">The ListBox that we're writing to.</param>
    public ListBoxTraceListener(ListBox listBox) {
        this.listBox = listBox;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Automatically collects the outputs from all Trace.WriteLine statements.
    /// Pre:  none.
    /// Post: the string s is displayed in the listBox.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    public override void WriteLine(string s) {
        Write(s + NEW_LINE);
    } //end WriteLine

    /// <summary>
    /// Automatically collects the outputs from all Trace.Write statements.
    /// Pre:  none.
    /// Post: the string s is displayed in the listBox, once we receive a NEW_LINE.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    public override void Write(string s) {
        stringToAddToListBox += s;

        // If we have one or more complete lines
        if (stringToAddToListBox.Contains (NEW_LINE)) {

            // Split the string into multiple lines. 
            // If NEW_LINE is found at the beginning or end of the string, 
            // then the corresponding array element contains an empty string. 
            string[] lines = stringToAddToListBox.Split(NEW_LINE);

            // Add all the lines to the listbox, except for the last one.
            // When stringToAddToListBox has a new-line at the end, 
            // the last element in lines[] will be an empty string.
            int highestLineNumber = lines.Length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < highestLineNumber; i++) {
                AddToListBox(lines[i]);
            }

            // Reset stringToAddToListBox to what remains. (May be an empty string).
            stringToAddToListBox = lines[highestLineNumber];
        }
    } // end Write

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a complete output-line to the ListBox.
    /// Pre:  none.
    /// Post: the string listBoxLine is displayed in the listBox    .
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listBoxLine"></param>
    private void AddToListBox(string listBoxLine) {
        Debug.Assert(listBox != null, "listBox != null");
        listBox.Items.Add(listBoxLine);
    } // end AddToListBox
}
```

}

At this stage we are just trying to use the trace listener to output some text on in the `ListBox` so we know it is working, so we have an event handler setup:

```
private void RollDiceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

We haven't been able to get any output from the trace listener. The `Add` method as the trace listener is not set up for that. Can anyone provide some suggestions please? I think maybe we are doing something really stupid and obvious that we have missed.

Comment: Throwing an exception for a parameterless constructor doesn't really make sense to me.  Implement a constructor that takes arguments and let the compiler indicate that there is an error if someone tries to create a new instance with 0 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of your issue is that your application is single threaded (as most simple Windows applications are). This means that although you are sending messages to the listview to append a new element to the list, the message **is not yet** handled just because your original handler hasn't returned yet (the `RollDiceButton_Click`).

To work this around, you should **force** the list to refresh itself from within the current handler:

```
private void AddToListBox(string listBoxLine) {
    Debug.Assert(listBox != null, "listBox != null");
    listBox.Items.Add(listBoxLine);
    // this would help? 
    listBox.Refresh();
} // end
```

If this doesn't help, try temporarily switching to unconditional processing of all pending events with

```
private void AddToListBox(string listBoxLine) {
    Debug.Assert(listBox != null, "listBox != null");
    listBox.Items.Add(listBoxLine);
    // this would help? 
    Application.DoEvents();
} // end
```

and report back.